# Conditional IF statement for mixed range of inputs (not in chronological order)

Tags: excel, if-statement

My situation is this: I'm trying to create a conditional IF statement that tests whether a cell falls within a mixed range of data and outputs a specific result. To be more specific, I want to search a range of serial numbers that correlate to a specific model year, however the serial numbers are not in numerical order (i.e. SN's 202-235, 241, 247-255 are model year 2015, and SN's 257, 201, 259-269 are model year 2016). Is there a way to create this?

Comment: Create a table with all the SN and the appropriate model year, then use vlookup to return the correct model year.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved using a similar solution to the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726009/how-to-convert-excel-values-into-buckets/47444295#47444295).

I've modified the formula to match your example

```
=INDEX({"",2016,2015,"",2015,"",2015,"",2016,"",2016,""},LARGE(IF([INPUT_VALUE]>{0,200,201,235,240,241,246,255,256,257,258,269},{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}),1))
```

Replace **[INPUT_VALUE]** with the appropriate cell reference and make sure to press **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** as this is an array formula.

This solution works by finding the largest number that the input is greater than in the second array, and then cross referencing the first array. The third array is being used as a counter for this cross referencing.

This may not be the most intuitive solution, but I believe it is the most flexible as it evaluates the number directly and can deal with numbers not explicitly specified.