Scoring values including NA() - Excel 365
Let's say I have the following array of numbers:
$222.71 
$370.00 
$224.93 
#N/A
$230.00 
$175.00 
$160.00 
$248.00 
$150.00 

I would like to score/rate the numbers above using some arbitrary criteria. For example, if the value is within 15% of the minimum, it gets a score of 3; if it is within 50% of the minimum, it gets a score of 2; if it is above 50% of the minimum or NA(), it gets a score of 1.
I would like the formula to be flexible and easy to maintain, as there might be many more relative value-based conditions.
=LET(
    values, A1:A9,
    minValue, MIN(FILTER(values,ISNUMBER(values))),
    rank, IF(ISNUMBER(values), IF(values <= minValue * 1.15, 3, IF(values <= minValue * 1.5, 2, 1)), 1),
    rank)

The above works but it's messy to read and maintain.
Using SWITCH makes it more readable and easier to maintain but it looks to long:
=LET(
    values, A1:A9,
    minValue, MIN(FILTER(values,ISNUMBER(values))),
    rank, IFERROR(
        SWITCH(TRUE(),
        values <= minValue * 1.15, 3,
        values <= minValue * 1.5, 2,
        1),
    1),
    rank
)

Are the better, more elegant ways of doing it?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2733218/11683?

For one thing, you don't need to define rank and then immediately return it.  You can safely delete both instances of , rank from your code for the same result.

@Chronocidal - quite so but it really doesn't answer my question.  This is just a convention I use for easier debugging in more complex formulas.

First Tip: take a look at the AGGREGATE function (and the related SUBTOTAL function): you can change minValue to be AGGREGATE(5, 6, values) instead of MIN(FILTER(values,ISNUMBER(values)))
Next tip is to use XLOOKUP, and build  a lookup columns, by multiplying minValue by an array of your bounds.  (Note that an Array separates Rows with ;, and Columns with ,)
Based on your data (a minValue of 150), this gives lookup columns of:



minValue*{1.5; 1.15}
{2; 3}




225
2


172.5
3



Doing an Approximate XLOOKUP on this, looking for the Next Largest Item (to get our <= results), and returning 1 when no match is found (i.e. >minvalue*1.5) can be done like this: (the second , 1 is what determines <= rather than the default of =)
XLOOKUP(values, minValue*{1.5; 1.15), {2; 3}, 1, 1)

This gives you a final function that looks like this, and can be easily expanded for however many "buckets" you want to include:
=LET(values, A1:A9,
    minValue, AGGREGATE(5, 6, values),
    IFERROR(
        XLOOKUP(values,
            minValue*{1.5; 1.15},
            {2;3},
            1,
            1),
        1
    )
)

Then, if you wanted to change from 1.5 and 1.15 to 1.75, 1.5 and 1.25 (and make the top result 4 instead of 3) then you would just have to extend the two Lookup arrays in the XLOOKUP
minValue*{1.75; 1.5; 1.25},
{2; 3; 4}

Much simpler than adding entire new conditions to a SWITCH!

Nice/creative way of using XLOOKUP.

You may also choose to make use of TOCOL which has a parameter to skip error values (such as #N/A) in combination with IFS, which returns the first found TRUE condition. If not are found (or the input is #N/A, the output of IFS is #N/A, so wrapping it in IFNA catches all values IFS didn't:
=LET(n,A1:A9,m,MIN(TOCOL(n,2)),IFNA(IFS(n<m*1.15,3,n<m*1.2,2),1))
